# Код работает неправильно (высчитывает неверное значение)

Tags: c

```
 #include<stdio.h>

int main ()
{

int a;
float c = 0;

printf ("сколько всего значений?\n");
scanf ("%d",&a);

printf ("\nзапись значений:\n");

int b[a];



for (int count = 0;count < a;count++)
{
    scanf ("%d" ,&b[count]);

    getchar();

}


for (int count = 0;count < a;count++)
{
    c = c + b[count];
}

c = c / a;

printf ("\nсреднее значение = %.2f",c);


return 0;
}
```

/*Смысл кода в том что бы высчитывать среднее арифметическое значение, но вместо этого компилятор
выдает иной ответ; вот пример компиляций:

сколько всего значений?
5

запись значений:
5
5
5
4
2

среднее значение = -349808576.00*/

Comment: код отлично работает и выдает корректный результат.

Comment: Уберите этот `getchar()` - зачем он вам? вполне работает и без него: https://ideone.com/4QNloE Впрочем, непонятно даже, зачем вам вообще массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите этот `getchar()` - зачем он вам? вполне работает и без него: https://ideone.com/4QNloE Даже интересно, как вам удалось заставить программу выдать неверное значение?...

Но зачем вам вообще этот массив? Не проще ли так:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int n;
    float avg = 0;
    printf ("сколько всего значений?\n");
    scanf ("%d",&n);
    printf ("\nзапись значений:\n");

    for (int count = 0; count < n; ++count)
    {
        int k;
        scanf("%d",&k);
        avg += k;
    }
    avg /= n;
    printf ("\nсреднее значение = %.2f",avg);
}
```